# Licensing SharePoint webparts

Tags: sharepoint, licensing

I want to license some SharePoint webparts. I would like to have a trial period, and then do an internet activation.

How should I handle farm scenarios?

Do I need to setup a licensing webservice on a proprietary server, or would it be better to use a 3rd party solution? If so, which one would you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't answer the licensing server part but most companies charge per web front end for farm scenarios.

Comment: any hints regarding implementation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is going to offer an application market place for SharePoint 2010 apps, see: http://www.readwriteweb.com/enterprise/2009/11/microsoft-to-offer-application.php

It is probably simplest for you to offer your webpart through that site once it comes online.

Comment: +1 for the link but have to say I am sceptical - hope its better than the office market place and article from 2009 - What year is it now? ;)